# Operation must use an updateable query error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am getting an error while trying to update field in same table.

```
UPDATE RawDataAll
SET RawDataAll.[90_ Day_Excess] = 
(
SELECT RawDataAll.ExtCost_Excess90
FROM RawDataAll 
WHERE (([RawDataAll.ExtCost_Excess90]=
    IIf([RawDataAll]![QOH]-[RawDataAll]![90_Days_Demand]>0,
        [RawDataAll]![QOH]-[RawDataAll]![90_Days_Demand],0)))
);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain (in words) exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the exact error, we could help.